# How to use Youtube API Key in development mode?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Should i remove all the restrictions while using 'youtube data api v3' (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) in development mode and then add restrictions when testing is done?

Is is possible to use localhost in some format, I'm not sure how a port will be specified in this case.
Is this safe to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to use `localhost`, since it has no meaning if you're thinking of the restrictions that are under the section ***Application restrictions** An application restriction controls which websites, IP addresses, or applications can use your API key. You can set one application restriction per key.* Those IPs are to be checked on YouTube's server side. Please elaborate a bit; then I may try to help you further.

Comment: Then what is the proper way to test locally before deployment?

Comment: I see no other way (though not done that myself), but to mock the API; no in its entirety, only the parts that you're actually using. Mocking the API is dependent of the app's implementation environment/language. Yet conceptually is straightforward to imagine it.

Comment: To avoid mocking the API, I myself have been using caching: that is I stored locally the JSON response provided by the API into a database of key/value pairs, where the keys were API invoking URLs and the values those JSON response texts. Thus while developing the app, having to repeatedly invoke APIs, the app in fact gets data from cache instead of the remote YouTube server. Caching is good in the deployment stage too, albeit likely functioning with a different logic than that belonging to the development stage.